# Universal Windows 10 App. How to use Back Button? VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, win-universal-app, uwp

In my application the app closes if the back button is pressed on a child page.

How can I called Frame.Navigate on a back button press?

I have seen examples how to do this in C# but these do not seem to translate over too well into VB.NET.

Below is a method of which I have tried

```
Private Sub OnHardwareButtonsBackPressed(sender As Object, e As Windows.UI.Core.SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested)
        Frame.GoBack()
    End Sub
```

This throws a hicup at declaring the type of event.

Also trying to handle the event `Windows.UI.Core.SystemNaviationManager` although this had no success in intercepting the back button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
Private Sub OnHardwareButtonsBackPressed(sender As Object, e As BackRequestedEventArgs)
    ' Tell the app that you have handled the event
    ' Otherwise, the back button will be processed normally and the app will close
    e.handled = true
End Sub
```

Then, to attach your event:

```
AddHandler SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested, AddressOf OnHardwareButtonsBackPressed
```

Comment: Fantastic, This works well. Just need to add one line in order to complete this. I will make an edit for anyone else in the future!

Answer (score 0):

Modified the suggested code above for anyone looking for a VB.Net code to implement an App's Back button, add the ff into your Page2(the page loaded from your Main page):

1. Add namespace: Windows.UI.Core.SystemNavigationManager
2. Add this code in Page2's Loaded event

GetForCurrentView.AppViewBackButtonVisibility = Visibility.Visible

AddHandler GetForCurrentView.BackRequested, AddressOf OnAppButtonsBackPressed

3. Add handler

Private Sub OnAppButtonsBackPressed()

If Frame.CanGoBack then Frame.Goback()

End Sub